# How to backup my iPhone without access to Internet, PC or a Mac?

Tags: iphone

I have unlimited data available on my phone, but my plan does not let me create 
a mobile hotspot. So I can’t even share my own data. I am also in a place where I do not have access to Internet or a computer and my iPhone needs to be backed up.

Is there any way I could possibly get this done?

Answer (score 5):

You can enable iCloud backup in your settings. You will not need to create a hotspot, only use your data to upload the backup to your iCloud account.

Comment: @user3439894, OP states that they have unlimited data on their phone plan. The post implies that they can use this, but they can't tether it to allow some other device to backup their phone. Their reference to not having internet access appears to refer to computer provided (e.g. cable, dial up) access, not their mobile data access.

Comment: Sorry, I took "I am also in a place where I do not have access to Internet" as meaning they are not able to use the unlimited data to backup their iPhone. Doesn't one have to have Internet Access to access iCloud? I won't know as I have never used iCloud, even though I have an iPhone.

Comment: One would need internet access to access iCloud. If they don't have internet access directly from their phone or a computer to access, there is no way for them to back up their phone.

Answer (score 1):

A mobile hotspot would not help in this scenario - that is to enable other devices to connect to the internet through your iPhone - but requires, of course, that your phone can already connect to the internet. It would not help your connect you phone to the internet; for that you would need a net-connected computer or WifI.

If you have no internet connection & no computer, you cannot make a backup.